# Isomorphism of Weil representations only when $E/F$ is Galois?

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, langlands-program

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ind}{Ind}\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal}$Let $F$ be a $p$-adic field, and let $E \subseteq \overline{F}$ be a finite extension of $F$.  Let $k_F$ and $k_E$ be the residue fields of $F$ and $E$, so $k_F \subseteq k_E$.  Let $I_F \subseteq W_F \subseteq \Gal(\overline{F}/F)$ be the inertia and Weil groups of $F$, and define the Weil group of the finite field $k_F$ by $W_{k_F} := W_F/I_F \subseteq \Gal(\overline{k_F}/k_F)$.

If $(\rho,V)$ is a finite dimensional representation of $W_E$, then $$\rho^{I_E}=V^{I_E} = \{v \in V : \rho(x)v = v \textrm{ for all } x \in I_E\}$$ is well defined as a representation of $W_E/I_E = W_{k_E}$.

Consider the two representations

$$\big(\Ind_{W_E}^{W_F}\rho \big)^{I_F} \space \space \space \space \space \Ind_{W_{k_E}}^{W_{k_F}}\rho^{I_E}$$

of $W_{k_F}$.  Consider an element $f$ of the left hand side.  It is a function $f: W_F \rightarrow V$ satisfying

$$f(yx) = \rho(y)f(x) \tag{$y \in W_E, x \in W_F$}$$

$$f(xz) = f(x) \tag{$x \in W_F, z \in I_F$}$$

Assume that $E/F$ is Galois, then $I_F \cap W_E = I_E$ is normal in $W_F$, which implies that

$$\rho(y)f(x) = f(yx) = f(x(x^{-1}yx)) = f(x)$$

for all $y \in I_E, x \in W_F$.  Hence $f$ actually maps into $V^{I_E}$, which gives us a map from the left hand side to the right hand side.

Deligne (Prop. 3.8.1, *Les Constants des Equations Fonctionelles des Fonctiones L*) indicates that these two representations of $W_{k_F}$ are always isomorphic.  But I seem to be only able to get a map from one to the other when $E/F$ is Galois.  Are these representations really the same?

Comment: Note that $W_{k_F}$ is cyclic, generated by the Frobenius element. To check that the representations are the same, it suffices to check that they send Frobenius to the same thing.

Comment: In order to check that, I need to first identify the underlying spaces of the two representations, which I only seem to be able to do when $E/F$ is Galois.